# MVC passing array of classes to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, view

I have a project I am working on in MS VS 2012.  I have a class that pulls data down from a database and puts it into an array of classes. That part of the code works seamlessly. The part I am having issue with is getting the data to the view for display.  It seems that from the controller you should have the ability to pass classes through but I have not found it.

In the model

```
    public Guid BoxGUID {get;set;}
    [Required(ErrorMessage="A box number is required")]
    public int BoxID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please pick an option")]
    public string BCAppearance { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCTrash { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCPad { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCClean { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCStrap { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCDoc { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string BCMaint { get; set; }
    public string BCMaintNote { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string UBWrap { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string UBPiece { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string NPSec { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string NPDmg { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick an option")]
    public string NPHardware { get; set; }
    public string TruckNum { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }
    public int CompletedFlag { get; set; }
    //odd items for manipulating data
    public string curDate { get; set; }
    public string boxGUIDString { get; set; }
```

int the db code section:

```
            public BoxInfo[] getBox(int count)
    {
        string query = "select * from Box where CompletedFlag = '0'";
        BoxInfo[] boxInfo = new BoxInfo[count];

        //create boxinfo array
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oConn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                boxInfo[i] = new BoxInfo();
               // string test = rdr[0].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BoxGUID = new Guid(rdr[0].ToString());
                boxInfo[i].BoxID = (int)rdr[1];
                boxInfo[i].Date  = (DateTime)rdr[2];
                boxInfo[i].BCAppearance = rdr[3].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCTrash = rdr[4].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCPad = rdr[5].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCClean = rdr[6].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCStrap = rdr[7].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCDoc = rdr[8].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCMaint = rdr[9].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCMaintNote = rdr[10].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].UBWrap = rdr[11].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].UBPiece = rdr[12].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPSec = rdr[13].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPDmg = rdr[14].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPHardware = rdr[15].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].TruckNum = rdr[16].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].Images = rdr[17].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].CompletedFlag = 0;
            }

        }
        return boxInfo;
    }
```

in the controller

```
    namespace BoxCheckInApp.Controllers
   {
     public class AddBoxController : Controller
   {
    //
    // GET: /AddBox/
    public CodeDB D = new CodeDB();
    public CodeODB O = new CodeODB();
    public BoxInfo box = new BoxInfo();


    public ActionResult Boxes()
    {
        D.Open();
        int count = D.getRows();

        if (count != 0)
        {
            BoxInfo[] myBoxes = new BoxInfo[count];
            myBoxes = D.getBox(count);
            D.Close();


            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            String noBoxes = "There are no incomlete boxes to edit";
            D.Close();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

in the controller I need to pass myBoxes to the view.  My boxes is a BoxInfo object Array. Each object is one row of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with your Controller and View regarding the model. You don't need the `ViewBag` in this scenario.

```
public ActionResult Boxes() {
    D.Open();
    int count = D.getRows();

    if (count != 0) {
        BoxInfo[] myBoxes = new BoxInfo[count];
        myBoxes = D.getBox(count);
        D.Close();
        //just pass the model to the view.
        return View(myBoxes);
    } else {
        String noBoxes = "There are no incomplete boxes to edit";
        D.Close();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Once you pass the model to the View that is all you need to be able to access it after setting the `@model`. You get it by calling `Model` property in the View.

```
@model BoxCheckInApp.Models.BoxInfo[]
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Boxes";
}

<h2>Boxes</h2>

@foreach (var @box in Model) {
  <li>@box.BoxGUID</li>
}
```

by specifying `@model BoxCheckInApp.Models.BoxInfo[]` you let the Razor engine know what is the type in `Model` property.

Comment: This solution worked as well, is there any downside to using the view bag over this method in terms of performance?

Comment: Performance, no. They all end up in the `ViewData` of the controller. usability however is better as the Model is a concrete type while the `ViewBag` is dynamic. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I have been playing around with it a bit and realized two things, I made an error in my loop, and I figured it out.

in the db section I corrected the loop

```
     do
            {
                boxInfo[i] = new BoxInfo();
                boxInfo[i].BoxGUID = new Guid(rdr[0].ToString());
                boxInfo[i].BoxID = (int)rdr[1];
                boxInfo[i].Date = (DateTime)rdr[2];
                boxInfo[i].BCAppearance = rdr[3].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCTrash = rdr[4].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCPad = rdr[5].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCClean = rdr[6].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCStrap = rdr[7].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCDoc = rdr[8].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCMaint = rdr[9].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].BCMaintNote = rdr[10].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].UBWrap = rdr[11].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].UBPiece = rdr[12].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPSec = rdr[13].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPDmg = rdr[14].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].NPHardware = rdr[15].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].TruckNum = rdr[16].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].Images = rdr[17].ToString();
                boxInfo[i].CompletedFlag = 0;
                i++;
            } while (i < count - 1);
```

Then in the controller I used viewbag

```
     public ActionResult Boxes()
    {
        D.Open();
        int count = D.getRows();

        if (count != 0)
        {
            BoxInfo[] myBoxes = new BoxInfo[count];
            myBoxes = D.getBox(count);
            D.Close();

            ViewBag.boxes = myBoxes;
            return View(myBoxes);
        }
        else
        {
            String noBoxes = "There are no incomplete boxes to edit";
            D.Close();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I realize I need to fix my else section which I will do next

then in the view

```
     @model BoxCheckInApp.Models.BoxInfo[]

     @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Boxes";
      }

      <h2>Boxes</h2>


      @foreach (BoxCheckInApp.Models.BoxInfo box in ViewBag.boxes)
      {
      <li>@box.BoxGUID</li>
      }
```

Apparently you need to change what you call @model to an array for it to work, and then you have to call the namespace. I did not find any help regarding this online, so hopefully it will help someone else out there.